# ASP.Net buttons do not fire but in second

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, button

I have a CSS-customized control, which is updated whenever a post-back happen. anyway, it affecting the buttons, link-buttons, image-buttons in which the buttons do not fire their supposed events but in the second click.

this is my JavaScript code....

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var init = function () {
        var B = document.getElementById("hfProgress");
        var slider2 = new rSlider({
            target: '#slider2',
            values: ['0.0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'],
            range: false,
            set: [B.value],
            tooltip: true,
            onChange: function (vals) {
            }
        });
    };

    window.onload = init;

})();
```

what can I do to make buttons fire in first click as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime in diagnosis, i found that the button is on Autopostback.. I set this Autopostback to off and then it worked fine